# Flask cookies.get in Safari

Tags: javascript, python, cookies, flask, safari

I set cookie in HTML via JS and after that get in in Flask app and print

JS Part:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        document.cookie = "screen_color="+screen.colorDepth;
        document.cookie = "screen_height="+screen.height;
        document.cookie = "screen_width="+screen.width;
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Flask part:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    screen_color = request.cookies.get('screen_color')
    screen_height = request.cookies.get('screen_height')
    screen_width = request.cookies.get('screen_width')
    print(screen_color, screen_width, screen_height)
    return 'ok'
```

In Chrome anything ok: i load page and python prints cookie values, but in Safari Python prints None.

What i'm doing wrong?